# Spring Cloud Stream and sending messages to queue in batches

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm sending messages to my message queue like this

```
 messages.forEach(message->
    sources.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
```

Those messages come from an external source and there could be thousands of them.
I've seen the Splitter but it requires an input channel and output channel, but my messages are going into the queue for the first time, I'm just producing messages not consuming them, and I'm not sure how Aggregator would work or if it would be too complex for such a simple scenario.

So basically I'd like to be able to send those messages in batches, rather than one by one.
How could that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

For something simple you can collect and create a `List` of data (messages or just payloads) and then create a single Message with List being a payload and send it.

For more configurable approach you can also use [Spring Integration Aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator)

Comment: what if the list is too large?

Comment: I don't know what that means. What is "too large"? There are so many variables involved that need to be known before even thinking on how to answer it. . . What is your SLA? What messaging system you are using? What is your expected bandwidth? What is your hardware specification etc., etc., etc.

Comment: It's Pub Sub on GCP. I don't know the other details as those haven't even been provided. Also, the idea is to make the solution cloud agnostic as much as possible, and I would make the batch size configurable. Each message represents a line in a CSV file, that ranges from 1-20000 lines, each line could be 200 chars max, so in the very worst case, it would be 4 MB.

Comment: Look at the aggregator as mentioned in original reply. No need to reinvent something that has already been battle tested. Also, the "1-20000 lines, each line could be 200 chars max" still is meaningless without the context of hardware, bandwidth, etc. . . It is all relative.